# show that if $\lim_{r\to\infty} \min_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ converges to a positive limit, and it's holomorphic then it's constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and $$\lim_{r \to \infty} \min_{|z|=r}|f(z)|>0$$
show that the function is constant.

It is probably somehow related to Liouville's theorem.
I am able to show that the function is bounded from below. And I thought about taking $-f$ and show it converges to, and therefore is bounded above. but I believe it isn't formal enough.

Does anyone have a formal explanation?

Comment: nice, given it's positive, can you show the claim holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$ g(z)=\frac{1}{f(1/z)}.$$

Then $g$ is holomorphic and bounded on a small punctured neighborhood of $0$. So $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $g$. This tells that $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)$ exists, which then proves that $f(z)$ converges as $z\to\infty$. (The possibility of $|f(z)|\to\infty$ as $z\to\infty$ is excluded by the condition.) Therefore $f$ is bounded and hence constant.